# Retry all HTTP calls if one fails in Angular 2 when one is dependant on another

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-http

Taking this Angular 2 code which makes a http call to './customer.json' and then uses a url returned in that to make a further call. How do I make it retry both calls if the second one fails using the rxjs retry method? Currently it just seems to retry the second one.

```
this.http.get('./customer.json')
.map((res: Response) => {
    this.customer = res.json();
    return this.customer;
})
.flatMap((customer) => {
    return this.http.get(customer.contractUrl)).map((res: Response) => res.json()
})
.retry(1);
```

So if `this.http.get(customer.contractUrl))` fails how do I make it retry both `http.get('./customer.json')` and `this.http.get(customer.contractUrl))` again.

Comment: That should be work...are you sure there is no caching at play here? Or could you provide jsbin to replicate your issue?

Comment: assigning a value inside of `map` is not a good practice. Try to use `do` operator to make the assignment

Comment: what about `this.http.get('./customer.json').retry(1).map...`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why my original code doesn't seem to work but I tried using the catch method instead and it seems to work.

```
makeCall(isRetry = false){
    return this.http.get('./customer.json')
        .map((res: Response) => {
            this.customer = res.json();
            return this.customer;
        })
        .flatMap((customer) => {
            return this.http.get(customer.contractUrl)).map((res: Response) => res.json()
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (isRetry === false){
                return this.makeCall(true);
            }

            return Observable.throw(err);
        });
}
```

I'll make some jsbins and see if I can figure it out